# r fit logistic curve through a scatterplot

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot a logistic trendline through the scatter plot data, however, I do not know how to go on about this. I searched the web and found functions that require 3 parameters, but I don't know how to find these. any help would be greatly appreciated.

The data:

```
    x          y
1    0 36.4161850
2    0 94.2196532
3    0 94.7976879
4    0 98.2658960
5    0 97.1098266
6  250 40.4624277
7  250 41.0404624
8  250 23.6994220
9  250 48.5549133
10 250 61.2716763
11 500  5.7803468
12 500  3.4682081
13 500  0.5780347
14 500  2.8901734
15 500  0.0000000
16 750  0.0000000
17 750  0.0000000
18 750  0.0000000
19 750  0.0000000
20 750  0.0000000

dummy <- structure(list(x = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "250", "250", "250", 
"250", "250", "500", "500", "500", "500", "500", "750", "750", 
"750", "750", "750"), y = c(36.4161849710983, 94.2196531791908, 
94.7976878612717, 98.2658959537572, 97.1098265895954, 40.4624277456647, 
41.0404624277457, 23.6994219653179, 48.5549132947977, 61.271676300578, 
5.78034682080925, 3.46820809248555, 0.578034682080925, 2.89017341040462, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), reshapeLong = structure(list(varying = structure(list(
    Proportion = c("m0.perc", "m250.perc", "m500.perc", "m750.perc"
    )), .Names = "Proportion", v.names = "Proportion", times = c("m0.perc", 
"m250.perc", "m500.perc", "m750.perc")), v.names = "Proportion", 
    idvar = "id", timevar = "Distance"), .Names = c("varying", 
"v.names", "idvar", "timevar")), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I'm aiming for is a logistic curve that starts high and ends low, a mirrored "S" if you like, through the scatter plot data.

```
plot(y~x, data = dummy)
```

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: from looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function, seems this would be a good start. had a play with the function to see appropriate parameter signs / shape of curve `f = function(L, k, x0, x) L / (1 + exp( -k* (x - x0))) ; plot(f(100, -0.01, 300, 1:600), type="l")` (not very structured approach!) . Try fitting `minpack.lm::nlsLM(y ~  L / (1 + exp( -k* (x - x0))),                       start=c(L=100, k=-0.1, x0=300 ), data=dummy)` . [ remember to do `dummy$x <- as.numeric(dummy$x)` as currently it is character ]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, your answer is confusing to me. The first part does draw a graph, but it doesn't overlay this on the scatter. The second part of your answer fits a model, but doesnt fit anything?

Comment: you wrote that you wanted to fit a curve but needed to estimate parameters. The nonlinear model in the comment above estimates these. The initial function f, and plot was used to find the start parameters for the nlsLM function. To do the final plot, you can use predict on the model , similar to the way you would a fitted line if you were doing linear regression.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation, a little bit more work than Gilles answer but with same results

Comment: Sure, but (imo) it is worth making the effort to see how to solve nonlinear regression problems in a more standard / general way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `drc` (for dose response curves) may be helpful.

You can estimate logistic curves for continuous data with 3 or 4 parameters.The function automatically find nice starting values for the optimisation alorithm (in contrast with `nls` for example). It has also easy plotting methods.

Here is an example with 3 parameters (argument `fct = L.3()`). The fourth parameter is the lower asymptote and is fixed to be 0. With a four parameters model the lower asymptote is estimated.

```
> dummy$x <- as.numeric(dummy$x)
> 
> library("drc")
> mL <- drm(y ~ x, data = dummy, fct = L.3(), type = "continuous")
> summary(mL)

Model fitted: Logistic (ED50 as parameter) with lower limit fixed at 0 (3 parms)

Parameter estimates:

                Estimate Std. Error    t-value p-value
b:(Intercept)   0.013938   0.010315   1.351208  0.1943
d:(Intercept)  86.789553  10.417186   8.331382  0.0000
e:(Intercept) 248.714704  30.029077   8.282463  0.0000

Residual standard error:

 14.61229 (17 degrees of freedom)

> plot(mL, type = "all")
>
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like an easy solution. However, why did the x-axis change? can it be visualized like the orginal axis to run from 0 to 800 m?

Comment: This is because in ecotoxicology the x axis is a dose of a product and is often represented with a log scale. So log scale for x is the default. Use this to plot it on the original scale : `plot(mL, type = "all", log = '')` and look at `?plot.drc` for help on this method.